# How does this simplification involving logs work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

In one of my part exam paper solutions, the following equality is stated:

$$q^{\frac{log(n+1)}{log\frac{1}{q}}} = \frac{1}{n+1} \;\;\;\;\;\;\; q \in (0,1)$$

I am not able to see how this equality is derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this as I was typing the Latex. I'll share my solution here in case it helps anyone.

$$y := q^{\frac{log(n+1)}{log\frac{1}{q}}} = q^{\frac{log(n+1)}{-log(q)}}$$
$$\implies log(y) = -\frac{log(n+1)}{log(q)} log(q) = -log(n+1)=log(\frac{1}{n+1})$$
$$\text{So, } y = \frac{1}{n+1}$$